# Clipboard does not work using tigervnc, even with options enabled on client and server

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, vnc, xfce, tigervnc

I cannot get clipboard (<kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd> to work on a tigervnc session). The vncserver is running Ubuntu 18.04 and XFCE. I'm starting the server using the following command:

vncserver -xstartup ~/.vncxstartup

My xstartup file has the following contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
/usr/bin/autocutsel -fork
exec startxfce4
```

(The `autocutsel` command was added recently due to other answers here on SO, but it doesn't seem to help the issue).

I've checked `vncconfig` on the server, as well as client config menu, and have enabled all options to send and receive clipboard to and from client and server.

When I connect to the server (also from tigervnc on an Ubuntu client), I am not able to copy and paste text to or from the server. How can I go about troubleshooting this?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this by installing adding `vncconfig -nowin &` to my `~/.vnc/xstartup` file. That, in combination with `autocutsel -fork`, allows for copying and pasting to and from server and client.

```
#!/bin/sh
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
vncconfig -nowin &
autocutsel -fork
exec startxfce4
```

Answer (score 0):

On the right corner of the Linux, the scissor is located. right-click and close the default clipboard manager and then start with Tigervnc clipboard manager as :

```
$ vncconfig &
```

It will start the TigerVNC clipboard. So you can share the clipboard with the local and remote machine.

I have tested and worked this on Oracle Linux.

Comment: with an old version of TigerVNC server (1.1.0) it was working also with the clipboard manager (Klipper in my case) running. Now I have to close it otherwise I can't paste remotely. It only works if I clear the clipboard history. Since having the history is useful it would be nice to understand why do we need to close the local clipboard manager in order to get it working.